# Cannot connect to Google Compute Instance user

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

I have searched all over google for this issue but found no answere yet, so I thought asking here.

I have a google compute instance and I had a running putty ssh connection that worked flawlessly. But after I formatted my PC, everything went wrong.

I installed gcloud and done the whole procces of ssh again (`config-ssh`, adding ssh to key list and trying to connect), also I was trying to connect to my old user after I realized that I typed a different name to my windows user name. Suddenly I got the `No supported authentication` message. So I thought something is wrong with the ssh keys, But I realized that I cannot connect to my user even through the google web browser window, the connection is always stuck on `trying to connect` until timeout.

I would gladly appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gcloud compute ssh currently has a known problem and might not work on Windows.

Here's a workaround until we fix it: run "gcloud compute ssh INSTANCE --dry-run". This will output the command it tries to execute.
Copy that command. You can either add -W flag to it and run it, or replace ssh.exe with ssh-term.exe and remove the -o flags.
If gcloud is installed in a place like Program Files, you might also need to add "" around the path.

Comment: The above mentioned bug should be fixed now and gcloud compute instances ssh should be working on windows again.

Please update your cloudskd instalation by running

    gcloud components update

After this,  connecting to an instance via ssh should work with:

    gcloud compute ssh my-instance

Comment: After updating sshing from windows works for me. But my original problem is with my user on the server. Eventually I gave up searching for solution and I raised a new server (and also from financial reasons).

Thank you for your help anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, run the following command (replacing the word in capital letters) which will ensure that your SSH key is created if it was not created before: `gcloud compute ssh INSTANCE`

Then, follow these steps to add your SSH key to your project and SSH into your instance:

1- Copy the content of  `C:\Users\<username>\.ssh\ google_compute_engine.pub`(might be different path based on each Windows version) into the project metadata ([Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com) -> PROJECT -> Compute -> Metadata -> SSH keys -> Edit -> Add key).

If you want to log in as a different user, you can do it modifying it in the last word of the pasted text: `<username>@<hostname>`

2- Configure Putty. Go to Connection -> SSH -> Auth -> Browse and select your Putty  SSH key which should be located in `C:\Users\<username>\.ssh\ google_compute_engine.ppk)`and try to SSH into the instance.

3- If it doesn't work, remove the instance metadata because the instance metadata overrides the project metadata. To do that, go to Compute-> Compute Engine-> INSTANCE -> SSH keys -> Edit -> Click on every ‘x’ and save the changes.

Regarding your issue trying to access using the SSH button in the Developers Console, I’d reboot the instance if it’s not in production because there is a script that must be working properly in order to access from there: `/usr/bin/python /usr/share/google/google_daemon/manage_accounts.py --daemon`

I hope it helps.

Comment: 1. As I am trying to connect through gcloud ssh, it responses an error saying: `FATAL ERROR: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server
 sent: publickey)` many times 

Also I tried to restart but nothing changed.
(I tried to run the python and its running but nothing has changed).

Comment: Did you try to SSH with PuTTY using your SSH key?